# Error loading view if XIB is in DLL / library

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

I used to have my progress view controller in my current project. Then I decided to move it into a separate library project which I added to my project. I reference the project and it builds successfully. I can use everything from the library.

By "moving" I mean: I copied the XIB, the XIB.DESIGNER and the XIB.CS file to the library and included the XIB in the project and adjusted the namespace.

But when I try to run the application, the controller which I moved cannot be loaded. The error I get is:

> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInternalInconsistencyException
>   Reason: Could not load NIB in bundle:
>   'NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)' with name
>   'ProgressController'

If I check the iPhone simulator directory and open my APP bundle, I can see a couple of NIB files which all come from my main project. However, the NIB from the DLL is missing. I can see myLibrary.DLL and myLibrary.DLL.MDB as aliases. They point to the BIN/DEBUG directory of my project. No NIBs there either, just the DLL.

I'm totally puzzled. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoTouch 3 doesn't support XIB's in library projects.  This will be supported in MonoTouch 4.

Comment: Clear answer. :-) What's the planned release for MT4? What other changes are you planning to be in that release?